# Book on current state of knowledge on the genetics of intelligence

Tags: genetics, book-recommendation, intelligence

I'm looking for a book that gives a good summation of the current state of knowledge on the genetics underlying intelligence.

I have read textbooks on human population genetics but I'm looking for something more specific.

I'd be happy for pointers to any books on neuroscience, developmental psychology, genetics that give some coverage to this topic.

I am not really looking for a popular science book.

Comment: Are you more interested in population and evolutionary genetics of intelligence or more on the molecular genetics of intelligence?

Comment: I believe that all of these aspects are pertinent, but I am probably more interested in research that point to molecular genetics and neurophysiology.

Comment: If it doesn't have to be a book, but could also be an extended review article, one possibilities would be: Toga et Thompson, 2005 ( http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev.neuro.28.061604.135655 ) or Deary 2012 ( http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev-psych-120710-100353?journalCode=psych)

Comment: Yeah, sure. Add those as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For current overview-like texts of diverse research topics the "Annual Review" series provides a good oversight:

Toga et Thompson, Annual Review of Neuroscience, 2005: [GENETICS OF BRAIN STRUCTURE AND INTELLIGENCE](http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev.neuro.28.061604.135655)

Deary, Annual Review of Psychology, 2012: [Intelligence](http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev-psych-120710-100353?journalCode=psych)

For a very recent (and good) primary research study, - that will thus within its introductory paragraphs contain one very concise summary of the most current state of the field - one recommendation would be:

Sniekers, Nature Genetics, 2017: [Genome-wide association meta-analysis of 78,308 individuals identifies new loci and genes influencing human intelligence](https://www.nature.com/articles/ng.3869)

Comment: Thanks for that info that's exactly the kind of thing that I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

A very recent review has been written on this. See

[Plomin, von Stumm (2018)](https://www.nature.com/articles/nrg.2017.104?error=cookies_not_supported&code=0c74de0a-9ede-4c67-b020-6cc04ef6e909): *The new genetics of intelligence*.

For some of the latest genome-wide association studies, see:

[Hill, et al (2017)](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41380-017-0001-5): *A combined analysis of genetically correlated traits identifies 187 loci and a role for neurogenesis and myelination in intelligence*.

[Savage, et al (2017)](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/early/2017/09/06/184853.1): *GWAS meta-analysis (N=279,930) identifies new genes and functional links to intelligence.*

However, as Robert Plomin and Sophie von Stumm report, newer genome-wide association studies are on the way which account for a larger portion of the variance. So there is constant progress at the moment.

If you're interested in the neuroscience aspect of intelligence, I recommend Richard Haier's book [*The Neuroscience of Intelligence*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/110746143X).